# ruby installation error in mac terminal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, rubygems

I am trying to install ruby in my machine...
i am getting this error...
can you guys tell me how to fix it...
providing my code below

```
gem install
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
        Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)
    RajKumar-Thulasimanis-MacBook-Pro:andre Raj$ gem install
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
        Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)
```

Comment: did you give it a name of a gem to install ?

Comment: [Rubygems](http://rubygems.org/) is different from [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org). Read the [Mac installation guide](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/installation/).

Comment: @IvanChau: thanks for your reply I cloned form here https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.. and installed my gem command in the project directory as well as in the clone directory but still i am not successful...

Comment: @user3413185 If you want to use a gem, an argument is needed for `gem install`. E.g. `gem install ./nameOfGem-0.0.0.gem` in the directory.

Comment: @IvanChau: i went to rubygem directory and used gem install sass i got this error cd rubygems/
RajKumar-Thulasimanis-MacBook-Pro:rubygems Raj$ gem install sass
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Comment: By default, you don't have permission to write into the gems directory. The easy fix is to `sudo gem install sass`.

Answer (score 0):

On the Macintosh OS X platform, Ruby comes as a part of the operating system and there is no need to install it. "Mountain Lion" (10.8) had Ruby version 1.8; the new "Mavericks" has Ruby version 2.0. There are some significant differences between those two Ruby version including syntax that worked in 1.8 but is no longer valid in 2.0, as well as additional core types such as `Rational` and `Complex`.